# Fit Parent Div to Content up to Max-Height: 100%;

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have the following structure in my html:

```
<div id="parent1" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="height: 100%;></div>
<div id="parent2" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="childs_child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Classes `col-sm-12 col-md-6` are from the Bootstrap Grid System and make both `#parent` elements fit side by side on a large screen.  Both `#parent2` and `#child` size height automatically to the content of `#childs_child`.  The problem is if `#childs_child` content is large then the entire page scrolls.  I'd like for `#child` to scroll if `#childs_child` content is large.

I've tried setting `#parent2 { max-height: 100%; } #child { max-height: 100%; overflow-y: auto; }` but `#child` just grows to fit `#childs_child`.

I there a purely CSS way to accomplish this without setting a specific height on either `#parent2` or `#child` or do I need to use Javascript?  I' don't want to set a specific height property because when `#childs_child` content is small and scrolling is not necessary, I want `#parent` and `#child` to shrink to fit and not be full height of the page.

Comment: you might find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window?rq=1

Comment: @Igupta - Unfortunately, that's not exactly what I'm looking for.